# Whats the best way to uninstall an app on 7.0 Nought?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

When uninstalling apps on 7.0 nougat, is it best to use the App Mgr. or uninstall it directly from the screen dragging it to the uninstall area?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, using "drag to uninstall" and uninstalling from app manager area is **one and the same thing** - only the the former is a shortcut to the latter.

Here is why:

Consider an application dragged to be uninstalled:

[image]

It still accesses the built in uninstaller from App manager

[image]

When directly using the application manager to unistall:

[image]

The difference, is when you "drag to remove" or when using a completely different uninstaller from third-party developers.

[image]

Hope this helps